# What language to build a secure (from IP theft) form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am building a small business which revolves around a complex form. So far, I've been developing the form in Javascript. However, the fact that js is client side pretty much means all my efforts are exposed to possible theft. I've looked into obfuscation techniques, but due to the fact that there are de-obfuscators out there, securing the intellectual property is dicey at best.

Is there any way to secure my js code from theft? Is copyrighting or trademarking the code a feasible alternative? This project is pretty much of a niche, so if a competitor who used similar code suddenly appeared, it wouldn't be all that difficult to check. However, if someone else used my code as the basis for a server side app, then I'd be pretty much screwed. If js is not a viable language to develop in, is there a server side language which could do the job? What pitfalls await the project on the server side?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: "What pitfalls await the project on the server side?" - You'd have to tell us something about the project, and what your form does, before we could even begin to answer that.

Comment: Dont understand your question. html/js dom scripting is client side , and it is a good thing one can actually read the code an know what is happening on his computer. If you have things to hide , do it server side , with solutions like nodejs , php ,asp ...

Comment: `What pitfalls await the project on the server side?` Choosing your language. ;p

Comment: How complex is your javascript? Personally I've never encountered a website with javascript functionality that I felt I couldn't easily duplicate without even looking at the code so I'm skeptical that you're attributing a realistic value to it.

Comment: I really don't see how this is a '[specific programming question](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions),' so I'm voting to close as '[off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask).' Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for all the quick replies. Spencer, to answer your question, it's not so much that the scripting contains magic, it's just that there is a ton of code (lots of questions and interactivity). If someone else wants to duplicate what I've done, I wish them luck, but I'd rather not hand them my efforts on a platter of exposed code.

Comment: /shrugs In a day and age when a framework as complex and well designed as jQuery is being given away for free I don't believe many people out there are interested in stealing javascript. Unless you're using it to solve world hunger I don't think anyone would be interested even if you zipped it up and put a download link on your front page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to secure your intellectual property from theft: **Don't write your code in client-side javascript.**

The choice of server-side language is a bit broad in scope, but if you prefer javascript you can implement your "secret/proprietary" functionality as a webservice using Node.js and then make calls against that from your actual form (either via traditional postback or via AJAX).

Answer (score 2):

Assume that any Javascript code can be read by a human, no matter how much obfuscation you put in. If a web browser can interpret it, a human can.

Generally any sensitive data should be stored on the server side and any sensitive business functions/calculations should reside on the server side. You can still achieve the client side smoothness and feel by using AJAX to call the sensitive functions on the server side.

There is no "most secure" server side language. Use the one you're most familiar with and is most suited to your app. Web application security correlates with the developer and their knowledge rather than the actual language.